# Cannot delete my Elasticsearch data folder inbetween JUNIT tests

Tags: java, elasticsearch, junit

I cannot run my unit tests. Without the @After below I get an IndexAlreadyExistsException. With the code below I get an IOException saying that I cannot delete the data directory. If I manually delete this directory inbetween test runs, it works. I am new to Elasticsearch, what can I do?

```
 @After
 public void testCompleted() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, INvocationTargetExcaption, IOException
 {
    File testFile = new File("target/elasticsearch/data");
    FileUtils.deleteDiretory(testFile);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Elasticsearch Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html) in order to [delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-delete.html) your index, or alternatively make an [http delete request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices-delete-index.html)